# training small amount of data on the large capacity network

Tags: deep-learning

Currently I am using the convolutional neural networks to solve the binary classification problem. The data I use is 2D-images and the number of training data is only about **20,000-30,000**. In deep learning, it is generally known that **overfitting problems** can arise **if the model is too complex relative to the amount of the training data**. So, to prevent overfitting, the simplified model or transfer learning is used.

Previous developers in the same field did not use high-capacity models (high-capacity means a large number of model parameters) due to the small amount of training data. Most of them used small-capacity models and transfer learning.

But, when I was trying to train the data on high-capacity models (based on ResNet50, InceptionV3, DenseNet101) **from scratch**, which have about **10 million to 20 million parameters** in, I got a high accuracy in the test set.
(Note that the training set and the test set were exclusively separated, and I used early stopping to prevent overfitting)

In the ImageNet image classification task, the training data is about 10 million. So, I also think that the amount of my training data is very small compared to the model capacity.

Here I have two questions.

1) Even though I got high accuracy, is there any reason why I should not use a small amount of data on the high-capacity model?

2) Why does it perform well? Even if there is a (very) large gap between the amount of data and the number of model parameters, the techniques like early stopping overcome the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You're completely right that small amounts of training data can be problematic when working with a large model. Given that your ultimate goal is to achieve a "high accuracy" this **theoretical** limitation shouldn't bother you too much if the **practical** performance is satisfactory for you. Of course, you might always do better but I don't see a problem with your workflow if the score on the test data is legit and you're happy with it.

2) First of all, I believe ImageNet consists of 1.X million images so that puts you a little closer in terms of data. Here are a few ideas I can think of:

- Your problem is easier to solve than ImageNet
- You use image augmentation to synthetically increase your image data
- Your test data is very similar to the training data

Also, don't forget that 30,000 samples means (30,000 * 224 * 224 * 3 =) 4.5 billion values. That should make it quite hard for a 10 million parameter network to simply memorize your data.

3) Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: thank you very much! Your thoughtful reply helped me a lot.